# how to give condition on crystal reports field

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

i am having invoice table..
in this table i have added CHANGEADDRESS field, for anyone can change the clients address and on report it wil show Old address as wel as Changedaddress..

if there is changedaddress, it wil show the changeaddress field in reports
but
IF thers is no changed address, it should not show the changedaddress field in reports..

plzz help out for the condition

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the changedaddress field on the report canvas then goto format field. On the common tab, next to the suppress option there is a formula editor icon (labelled X-2) - click it. In the formula editor you can now enter:

```
isnull({table.changedaddress}) or {table.changedaddress} = ''
```

Click save and close and you're done.